# Loading a file into memory and then executing it (no operating system)

Tags: c, executable, bootloader, execution, 6502

My program (written in c) loads other programs into memory before executing them. This is the code I do that with:

```
void (*jumpToExec)(void) = (void (*)())0x0801;

void loadExecutable(char* executable) {
    cbm_k_setnam(executable);
    cbm_k_setlfs(0, 8, 0);
    cbm_k_load(1, 0x0801);

    jumpToExec();
}
```

(Please ignore the CBM-DOS calls, they are not relevant. They basically just identify a file and load it into memory)

`executable`, in this case, points to a program built from this code:

```
int otherMain() {
    printf("Hello, world!");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How do I run the function `otherMain()` in this separate program when the function `loadExecutable()` in the main program loads it?

Comment: There's no standard way to do this. It may require using assembly.

Comment: If your compiler can generate a map file, you can probably see in that what the offset of the entry-point (the `otherMain` function) is, and you can add that to the load address, but what, then, about `printf` - that's going to rely on the O/S, no?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I have a toolchain called cc65 that helps with standard library stuff, but there is no available operating system (unless you count CBM-DOS or the CBM KERNAL).

Comment: If your program is supposed to execute another program, why is the function, in the other program, named otherMain and not main? The cc65 docs describe a function named exec, which executes a program. Have you looked at the exec function?

Comment: @Stuart oh, I didn't know about that. I'll look into `exec(...)` to see if it does what I need

Comment: You can't just cast an absolute address to a function pointer and call the function. The _calling convention_ has to match as well. Notably `void (*) (void)` is not compatible with `int (*)(void)` so they are unlikely to have the same calling convention. Maybe you can call the function but it will crash & burn when returning etc. Also many ISA want functions placed on even addresses and not on some obscure misaligned address like `0x0801`.

Comment: @Lundin $0801 (0x0801 in c) is the start of the user program RAM on the Commander X16. What's wrong with using that address?